# Why doesn't Environment in bean see properties from source in integration context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-environment

In my Spring Integration webapp configuration I've added a property placeholder:

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    ...
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            ...
            ">

    <ctx:component-scan ... />
    <ctx:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <ctx:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties" trim-values="true" />
```

This is that file content:

```
apiPath=/requests
```

I'm sure this configuration works because I've tried using that value in a http inbound-channel-adapter:

```xml
<int-http:inbound-channel-adapter id="/api${apiPath}"
        channel="httpRequestsChannel"
        path="${apiPath}"
        ...>
</int-http:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

and if I change the property value the frontend application cannot reach the endpoint.

However, further in the context I have an endpoint so configured:

```
<int:header-value-router input-channel="httpRequestsChannel" ... >
    <int:mapping value="POST" channel="httpRequestsPostChannel" />
    ...
</int:header-value-router>

<int:channel id="httpRequestsPostChannel" />

<int:chain input-channel="httpRequestsPostChannel">

    <int:transformer method="transform">
        <bean class="transformers.RequestToMessageFile" />
    </int:transformer>

    ...
```

where I want to read the property value:

```java
public class RequestToMessageFile {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    // ...

    public Message<?> transform(LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> multipartRequest) {
        System.out.println("Value: " + env.getProperty("apiPath"));
```

But on the console I see:

```
Value: null
```

I supposed once declared the property source in the XML that would be part of the whole web app environment, what am I missing? Should I declare the source in another place?

I noticed that if I add the following annotations:

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class RequestToMessageFile {
```

the property is correctly found so I guess this is just a configuration problem.

In case it matters, here's the `web.xml` portion that configures integration:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/META-INF/spring.integration/context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>  
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

---

### UPDATE

Partly following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50412392/3127111) I removed `<ctx:property-placeholder>` from the XML file and I added the following bean:

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class WebappConfig {

}
```

And now both beans and the XML file can see the properties.

Comment: No it isn't a configuration issue that is how it is supposed to work. The `<context:property-placeholder />` doesn't add properties to the environment. Where as the `@PropertySource` does.

Comment: @M.Deinum Then how can I declare the property source in only one place, for both the XML and all the beans? Or otherwise, what's the XML equivalent of `@PropertySource`?

Comment: There isn't. Just declare it in Java everything is part of the same application context.

Comment: You need to use `@PropertySource` and also declare a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` as a `static` `@Bean` in your `@Configuration`. And that everything instead of `<ctx:property-placeholder>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting Martin Deinum:

> No it isn't a configuration issue that is how it is supposed to work. The  doesn't add properties to the environment. Where as the @PropertySource does.

Therefore you should remove `<ctx:property-placeholder>` from your XML configuration. Continue to use `@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")` and also add this bean definition:

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

Pay attention how it has to be `static` do not load eagerly all other beans in the same `@Configuration`.

Comment: I removed the XML file entry and added a new bean (please see my _update_ above) and it works now; I'm new to Spring, can you elaborate on why I need that additional `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean?

Comment: Because that’s how it has to be configured with Java and Annotations configuration. See its JavaDocs for more info